# Dart pub get cannot download package

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I created a dart2 web project and ran pub get command. But some package cannot download with time out, here is screen shot: [screen-short-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcWO3.jpg). I can download these package directly from https://pub.dartlang.org/ then put these package to local pub_cache, then it works well. How can I download package via pub get command?

Comment: Are you using a proxy to access the internet?

Comment: It's works fine when using our company's network . I was used proxy in my personal network. Is there any options for proxy ?

Comment: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/troubleshoot

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks !